# Using "/" with require in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I do not understand the purpose of using "/" when requiring a package in Nodejs. For example for loading the Microsoft / Contributors Node V8 Driver for Node.js for SQL Server it needs to be required like this as per the [documentation](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server):

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
```

But these are two different node modules. What is the above require doing?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, require is just importing a specific file. `mssql/msnodesqlv8` means require `msnodesqlv8` from `mssql` package. File is here https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/blob/master/msnodesqlv8.js

On the other hand, everything before the `/` can be the package scope. When someone publishes a package, they need to give it a name, the package can be either user-scoped or organization-scoped. This helps to create a package with the same name as a package created by another user or organization without conflict.

More info:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages
- https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

I am not sure if scopes require a `@` character though.

Answer (score 1):

You can dive it from the document step by step:

> This driver is not part of the default package and must be installed separately by npm install msnodesqlv8@^2

1. Above says `msnodesqlv8` is a driver, but **to use this driver**:

> To use this driver, use this require syntax: const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8').

2. Above will **reference the file**: [mssql/msnodesqlv8](https://unpkg.com/browse/mssql@7.2.0/msnodesqlv8.js):

```js
module.exports = require('./lib/msnodesqlv8')
```

3. So **look at the file** [mssql/lib/msnodesqlv8/index.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/mssql@7.2.0/lib/msnodesqlv8/index.js)

```js
const base = require('../base')
const ConnectionPool = require('./connection-pool')
const Transaction = require('./transaction')
const Request = require('./request')
```

4. Then **the file** [./connection-pool.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/mssql@7.2.0/lib/msnodesqlv8/connection-pool.js) finally **required `msnodesqlv8` package**:

```js
const msnodesql = require('msnodesqlv8')
... ...
```

5. Above `require('msnodesqlv8')` will lookup and use the package you just installed.

It's like a chain, you grab the start(`mssql/msnodesqlv8`), but you got the end(`msnodesqlv8`) finally, the have similar names, but have different means.